# How do I initialize with a 2 dimensional initializer_list?

Tags: c++, matrix, initialization, initializer-list

I know, that vector class is initialized in the following way:

```
Vector::Vector(initializer_list<double> lst)
    :size{static_cast<int>(lst.size())},elem{new double[static_cast<int>(lst.size())]}
    {
        copy(lst.begin(),lst.end(),elem);
    }
```

Here is my Matrix class:

```
class Matrix{
private:
    int row;
    int col;
    double elem**
public:
    //Default Constructor:
    Matrix(int row,int col);
    //Initialized list constructor:
    Matrix(initializer_list<initializer_list<double>> lst);
```

I suppose, that I should use initialized lis in initialized list in order to create initialized matrix. How can I do it from the syntax point of view?

Comment: My compile-time Gung-fu is not sufficient to provide a compiler error if the matrix is not rectangular.

Comment: Shouldn't the default constructor be without arguments?

Comment: @user4581301 You don't have to: If you initialize a 2D array, the compiler will not complain either:  `int mat[3][3] = { {1,2,3}, {9}, {6,7} };`.  It's sufficient here to find the largest row to determine the column :-)

Comment: @Christophe Curses! You are right! An hour of my life not wasted though; I now know a lot more about `constexpr` and `static_assert` with respect to `initializer_list` than I did when I got up this morning.

Comment: @atru it depends if the matrix is resizable or not.  Of course, not having a default constructor would have some constraints (e.g. you could not construct a vector of n matrix).

Comment: @Christophe Thank you! I'm still learning, so the question. Got the point. I was solving a similar problem recently but it asked to use an allocator instead of new. A textbook implementation of a vector. I gave this a try but you were faster :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the same principle that you used for `Vector`, but iterating throug a list of list:

```
Matrix(initializer_list<initializer_list<double>> lst) : 
                                   row{lst.size()}, 
                                   col{0}   // not sure if all cols are same size
{
    for (auto &x: lst)     // iterate through outer list to find largest inner list
        if (x.size()>col)
            col = x.size();
    cout<<row<<"x"<<col<<endl;   // educational purpose only -> remove
    elem=new double*[row];       
    auto it=lst.begin();         // iterate through outer list 
    for (int i=0; i<row; i++, it++) {
        elem[i]=new double[col];    
        std::copy(it->begin(),it->end(),elem[i]); // copy current inner list
    }
}
```

With this you can handle a 2D list like:

```
Matrix m{ {1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
```

**[Online demo](https://ideone.com/WiDvcs)**

**Important remarks:**
It's always painful and error prone to manage memory manually.  It would be easier to use `std::vector` instead of pointers to dynamically allocated arrays.  For the matrix, you'd have the choice between a vector of vectors, or an flattened vector with some formula to find the element for a given row and column.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I feelt this pain(using of pointers), but I am doing this in order to get better intuition how they work.

Comment: Just one small question: can you explain me the line std::copy(it->begin(),it->end(),elem[i]); Why it's meant here, that we copied inner list, and not outer list?

because it means lst.begin().begin() ?

Comment: @Rob_Fir yes: 'it' is the iterator that goes through the items of the outer list. When dereferencing 'it' (e.g. either *it or it->) you address the item that the iterator is pointing at, which is here one of the inner list.  As this element is itself a list (inner list) you can use its members to get iterators to itself. So it->begin() is the start of one of the inner list.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use [`std::array`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/):

```
#include <array>

template<int ROWS, int COLUMS>
using Matrix = std::array<std::array<double, COLUMS>, ROWS>;

Matrix<3,3> m{ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0 };
```

Or [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/):

```
#include <vector>

using Matrix = std::vector<std::vector<double>>;

Matrix m{ {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}, {4.0, 5.0, 6.0}, {7.0, 8.0, 9.0} };
```

Or a `class Matrix` derived from `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>

class Matrix
    : public std::vector<std::vector<double>>
{
public:
    Matrix( std::vector<std::vector<double>> && m )
        : std::vector<std::vector<double>>( m )
    {}
};

Matrix m( { {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}, {4.0, 5.0, 6.0}, {7.0, 8.0, 9.0} } );
```